# One image divided by multiple tiles in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation

Is it possible to have multiple tiles(borderless windows forming a matrix) and each capture input separately?

Meaning, the tiles must appear as a whole, as one image, but receive input separately. The input tile is changed by clicking on another tile.

#### Motivation

I want to have a big image for sketching a big scheme; that image would be displayed by a projector; the input would come from a graphic tablet; and because the tablet's size is quite small for my needs, I need the image to be divided appropriately (I'm thinking, a 4x4 matrix).

Note:
It doesn't have to be photoshop. Any software that can do that and supports graphical tablets would do.

Comment: Yes its possible, use slices

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! I don't quite understand why you need to do this. Can't you just zoom in on different parts of the image when you draw like one would normally do? Are you going to do this for a live audience?

Comment: @Wolff, no. It's just the way I wan't to do "whiteboarding"(tell me another way, if you know a better one). For some reason I haven't thought about it. It probably would work. The only thing it laks is that you can't see the full image the whole time. But if it's possible to do some trickery... if there's a way to edit in one window that would probably be displayed on the PC, and have another window that would have the appropriate zooming and be displayed by the projector...

Comment: Well, I would have to know how your projector works to give a usable answer. But I can tell you that it *is* possible to have multiple windows showing the same image at different zooms. *Window > Arrange > New Window for filename* should do it. You can then zoom in in one of the views and have the other view set to show the whole image. You can use *Window > Arrange > Float in Window* to detach the latter from the main Photoshop window. If your projector then can be set to only show the detached window ...

Comment: Slices seems to be a dead end since it's mostly used if you want to export an image to smaller tiles.

Comment: @Wolff, are you saying they don't capture input separately? And you have tried with input devices other than mouse. Though, honestly, I don't know how an input such as a tablet behaves; is it like a mouse, meaning you can click on anything in the window, or the program translates the input to the specific area(the image view), or in varies from program to program?

Comment: Most operating systems can just split the image signal across multiple monitors. But offcourse its hard to say what your tablet does.

Comment: Normally a tablet behaves like a mouse. As you move the pen around, the cursor moves around on the screen. You hold the pen slightly above the surface when you want to move and let it hit the tablet when you want to click/draw/whatever. The area of the tablet corresponds to the area of the screen. You can customize the area of the tablet to use if your screen has a different aspect ratio than the tablet or if you don't want to use the full area of the tablet.

Comment: And about slices, no they don't capture input separately as far as I know. They are just a way to be able to save an image sliced up into smaller rectangles. Can be used for many things.

Comment: @Wolff, the solution with a floating seems to be perfect. Though it's a shame the change is shown in the floating window only after it (the action) has been completed; say, when you're drawing a line with a brush, the line isn't show in the floating until you lift up the left mouse button(in case of a mouse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Photoshop it's possible to have multiple windows showing the same document at different zooms.

Use *Window > Arrange > New Window for [filename]* to open another view of your document.

[image]

You can then use *Window > Arrange > Float in Window* to detach the new window from the main Photoshop window. Or you can simply drag the tab free from its place.

Now you can work zoomed in the original window while letting the new window show the full image.

[image]

Hopefully your projector can be set up to show the detached window, while you work in the main Photoshop window.

A tiny annoyance is that the other views of an image doesn't update while you draw, but only after you let go of the mouse button.